# Add Copyright to PDF File

Tags: c#

Will you review the syntax, structure, and logic of my code. It can be tested using the main.

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AddCopyRightPDF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string PDFPath = "D:\\SamplePDF\\SamplePDF.PDF";
            string PDFPathUpdated = "D:\\SamplePDF\\SamplePDFUpdated.PDF";

            byte[] b = AddCopyrighttoPDF(PDFPath);


            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(PDFPathUpdated, b);

        }

        public static byte[] AddCopyrighttoPDF(string path)
        {
            byte[] b = null;
            string CopyRighText;
            try
            {

                CopyRighText = "Copyright © " + DateTime.Now.Year + " All Rights Reserved.";
                PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;
                PdfReader pdfReader = null;
                try
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        pdfReader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(path), System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1111"));
                        pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms);
                        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                        {
                            if (i > 1)
                            {
                                Rectangle pageSizeWithRotation = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);
                                PdfContentByte overContent = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(i);
                                overContent.BeginText();
                                BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("Helvetica", "Cp1250", false);
                                overContent.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 7F);
                                overContent.SetRGBColorFill(0, 0, 0);
                                float n2 = 15F;
                                float n3 = pageSizeWithRotation.Height - 10F;
                                overContent.ShowTextAligned(0, CopyRighText, n2, n3, 0F);
                                overContent.EndText();


                            }
                        }

                        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                        pdfStamper.Close();
                        b = ms.ToArray();

                        ms.Flush();
                        ms.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    b = null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (pdfReader != null) { pdfReader.Close(); }
                }
            }
            catch { b = null; }
            return b;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From top to bottom**

Since `AddCopyrighttoPDF()` is a `public` method you should validate its argument `path`.

Variables should be named using `camelCase` casing and should be spelled correctly `string CopyRighText;` -> `string copyrightText;`

> ```
> try
> {
>
>     CopyRighText = "Copyright © " + DateTime.Now.Year + " All Rights Reserved.";
>     PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;
>     PdfReader pdfReader = null;
> ```

why are these 3 lines of code inside a `try..catch` block? Which exception could here happen? The `try..cacth` block can be removed.

You are using an `using` statement for the `MemoryStream` which is a good thing, but both `PdfReader` and `PdfStamper` are implementing the `IDisposable` interface as well hence they should be enclosed in an `using` block as well.

> ```
> for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
> {
>     if (i > 1)
>     {
> ```

If the loop would start at `int i = 2` the `if` block would become superflous which saves one indentation-level of thecode.

`BaseFont baseFont` should be created outside of the loop and reused.

`float n2 = 15F;` should be named better and should be a constant.

`float n3` should be named better.

`overContent.ShowTextAligned(0, CopyRighText, n2, n3, 0F);` here `0F` should be extracted into a constant as well.

Disposing of the `MemoryStream`, which happens when the end of the `using` block is reached will `Flush()` and `Close()` it as well.

Implementing the mentioned points will lead to

```
private const float copyrightFontHeight = 7F;
private const float copyrightHorizontalPosition = 15F;
private const float copyrightVerticalBorder = 10F;
private const float copyrightRotationNone = 0F;
public static byte[] AddCopyrighttoPDF(string path)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) { return null; }

    string copyrightText = "Copyright © " + DateTime.Now.Year + " All Rights Reserved.";

    try
    {
        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("Helvetica", "Cp1250", false);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(path), System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1111")))
        using (PdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms))
        {
            for (int i = 2; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                Rectangle pageSizeWithRotation = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);
                PdfContentByte overContent = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(i);
                overContent.BeginText();
                overContent.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, copyrightFontHeight);
                overContent.SetRGBColorFill(0, 0, 0);
                float copyrightVerticalPosition = pageSizeWithRotation.Height - copyrightVerticalBorder;
                overContent.ShowTextAligned(0, copyrightText, copyrightHorizontalPosition, copyrightVerticalPosition, copyrightRotationNone);
                overContent.EndText();
            }

            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            pdfStamper.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch { } //empty because if we just want to swallow the exception

    return null;
}
```

This should behave exactly like your former code. Thats why its not throwing an `ArguemntNullException` if `path == null` and why its not throwing an `ArgumentException` if `path` is whitespace only.

I couldn't find the C# documentation of `BaseFont` but if `BaseFont` is implementing `IDisposable` as well, it should be enclosed in an `using` block as well.